# best way to store/use multiple languages

Tags: c#

If I would want to create a c# application that support multiple languages, how should I store them?

I'd probably use constants in the application as value holders.

Such as:
Console.Write(FILE_NOT_FOUND);

When compiled, it would change into the string determined by the language.
I'll probably stick to 3 languages (Danish, English, Deutsch), not that I think it matters though.

It seems to be a waste to have a class file for each language, which all is processed when the application is compiled. It would also mean that you'd have to re-compile and re-distribute the whole program every time you want to change a string.
As far as I know, hardcoded strings is a bad thing.

Maybe a text file?
English.txt
Line1: FILE_NOT_FOUND=File Not Found. Try Again
Line2
Line3
etc.

Danish.txt
Line1: FILE_NOT_FOUND=Filen blev ikke fundet. Prøv igen
Line2
Line3
etc.

and so on.
If the user selects English, it reads the text file and set the different constant values.

The last one I can think of is placing it in a SQL database.

Could you give me some input? :)

Also, I tried writing FILE _ NOT _ FOUND (without spaces, but the text editor wouldn't let me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a resource file. That's the standard way to handle localization.

For details, [see this tutorial.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx)

--- EDIT ---

An alternative tutorial is [available here.](http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=211&printer=t)  This one uses much better naming, so it may be more clear how it works.

Comment: string msg = resourceMgr.GetString(messageId,ci);
I just saw this example. Isn't it extremely hard to keep track of the IDs and what they refer to?

Something like FILE_NOT_FOUND seems a lot easier to work with
Else, when programming, you have to look each ID up you find in your code

Comment: Using that example, it is.  But in .Net with Visual Studio you can get intellisense support for all the available strings.  Give them good names and you're gold.

Comment: Could you give an example/alternative to
string msg = resourceMgr.GetString(messageId,ci)?
I'd see it much more clear with a tiny example

Comment: caspert: I've added another tutorial.  It uses better names (ie: labelFirstName instead of messageId), so maybe it will make it more clear for you.

Comment: So the example could be:
radioSpanish.Text = m_ResourceManager.GetString("radioSpanish");

Thanks a lot, this is a LOT more clearer to me :) Now I am not near as intimidated by .NET's way of handling localization!

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Good luck with your project :)

Comment: @ReedCopsey the second link is "Not Found" and +1 for 1st one.

Comment: @ReedCopsey second link are dead

Answer (score 4):

I think your best option is to use the built in localization resources of the .NET Framework.  You can read more about the mechanics of that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x(VS.80).aspx).

As for using a database to store your localised elements (text, images and the like) this is certainly a common option, but I think it's mostely because developers understand getting data from a database, more than working with satellite assemblies and the like.  There a number of problems with using a database, so I'll name only a few: 1) added complexity of deployment of the application 2) addtional load on the database server, 3) where do you store the localized messages to say that the database is down :)

Using some sort of text file (likely XML) also carries with it some deployment issues, but more importanly the percieved flexibility of making text changes 'on the fly' is somewhat over rated.  Apart of spelling mistakes and awkward wording you'll almost always be shipping a new build as the text of your app changes.

Comment: I hadn't thought of reason 3 :) That is a very good one, haha.

"because developers understand getting data from a database, more than working with satellite assemblies and the like" - I can completely relate to that at the moment. So you'd suggest XML as the 2nd choice?

Comment: It seems that XML is now well enough understood be application administrators (thanks to things like Web.Config) that they won't faint at having to edit it --- it is also a fairly straightforward job to build a simple bespoke editor for your language file.  deployment is still an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Localization/Internationalization samples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688096.aspx

I've also heard good things about [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321341384).

Answer (score 0):

This topic is far too large for a reply.

The process of making a program ready for new languages is normally called "internationalization" or "i18n", and the process of taking that and actually making it run is "localization" or "l10n".

Briefly, you want to have hardcoded strings replaced by string resources, as you say, and then typically create different resource files for different languages.  Assuming you're working in .NET (a fairly good assumption for C#), there's a lot of stuff Microsoft does to make it easier.

Remember that there are other localization issues than language.  For example, the Danish currency symbol is probably not '$', but rather the Euro symbol, dates are almost certainly abbreviated differently, and many places use ',' for the decimal point and '.' for the thousands separator, opposite from the English practice.