# Using C#, how to allow editing of strings from outside the application?

Tags: c#, configuration, string

I'm looking for a way to have an external file (resources, resx, assembly, config, xml, etc) editable by a user of my application.

These would mostly contains strings of text related to database field names and the like.

Preferably, something with an already existing free editor. I wouldn't mind doing an app for this if needed though.

Does someone know of a preferred way to achieve this in the .net world?

---

### Update

I'm not looking to persist application settings.

Comment: What is the target user's skill level? Is this an end-user or an experienced programmer?

Comment: Are you trying to internationalize your application?  You may want to search SO for "[c#] internationalization, to find results like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678204/best-way-to-store-use-multiple-languages

Comment: Programmers mostly as it is data used internally by the application.

Comment: I am not trying to internationalize my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Application Settings (user scoped) for this, and use some large textbox or richTextEditor to edit the contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use User-scoped [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa928103.aspx) to provide this type of information.  You'd need to make an editor for this, if you want a GUI (usually this is just handled by a form in your app).